# Syntax behind how as_view() delivers callable, DJANGO

Tags: python, django

I will keep this question short. Similar questions on S/O do not address what I am wondering about, and I have struggled to find an answer.

When I point to a CBV in my urls.py, I use the as_view class method:

> ...MyView.as_view()...

Looking at the actual script (django/django/views/generic/base.py), the as_view returns a function 'view' that is specified within the actual class method itself. How come it returns the function with this line:

> return view

Why does it not have to specify:

> return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

I tried this out myself. I went and created a FBV_1 that returned yet another FBV_2 (the view responsible for delivering all functionality), in this same manner:

> return fbv_2

It generated an error. I had to return fbv_2(request) to access it.

Thank you in advance. Apologies for any idiomatic expression-errors, my Swedish sometimes gets the best of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing some important details in your investigation: 
The `as_view()` class method never takes hold of the request object or function arguments, it just returns a callable for the function it declares in [its definition](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py). Returning a callable is different to returning an object or in this case, a Response object. When an `url` object is evaluated, your code does something like the following, let's make some URL objects:

```
url(r'/some_pattern/', views.some_view)
url(r'/other_pattern/', views.ClassBasedView.as_view())
```

when I go to `/some_pattern`, `some_view` is defined as a callable, so it can be executed as a function:

```
views.some_view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

when I go to `/other_pattern/`, the class-based view is expected to return a callable after `as_view()`, which it does:

```
views.ClassBasedView.as_view()(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

this is evaluated to:

```
view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

which in turn is evaluated to:

```
self.dispatch(requests, *args, **kwargs)
```

where `self` is an instance of ClassBasedView, and dispatch always returns an HttpResponse of some sort:

```
HttpResponse('hello!')
```

So! after all this, if you don't see how your premise is faulty, let's complete your test, you have  the following:

```
def fbv_2(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponse('hello!')

def fbv_1(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return fbv_2
```

and the following URL definition:

```
url(r'/test/', views.fbv_1)
```

Then, when I point my browser to `/test/`:

```
views.fbv_1(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

which is evaluated to

```
views.fbv_2
```

Uhm, so what happened? well, the [Handler](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/handlers/base.py) expected some sort of HttpResponse, but instead received a function pointer, which he wont evaluate. You see, the `as_view()` method is what we call a **Factory**, its job is to create view functions based on what the class defines as instance methods, because the Handler can't understand instance methods, just functions.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed comment! What still is not clear to me is why: views.ClassBasedView.as_view() is evaluated to view(request, *args, **kwargs) from the line 'return view' ---- when views.fbv_1(request, *args, **kwargs) is evaluated to 'views.fbv_2' and not fbv_2(request, *args, **kwargs)? When I defined fbv_2 inside of fbv_1, making the cases completely similar - it still did not work. Why is that? How come as_view() can return a callable when my fbv_1 cannot - even though the conditions seem exactly the same (that is, when the definition of fbv_2 is included in fbv_1)?

Comment: How is it possible that as_view() does not take request? If I leave request out of FBV_1, I get the error: FBV_1() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given. Is the explanation simply that the url() recognises that as_view() is a factory - because of @classonlymethod and the arguments that it takes, and because of that let's it return a function - while the same of course is not true for my FBV_1?

Answer (score 1):

"view" is the function name name.

In this case we have defined the function within another function - as_view(). Think of the name "view" as a variable pointing to code rather than data.

```
view
```

is the function - we have defined it (within the as_view() function). It already knows what arguments to expect from the line:

```
def view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    ... 
    ..
```

A function is just code.

To execute the function you would usually type the function name followed by parenthesis enclosing any arguments.

```
view(request, kwarg1=var1 , kwarg2=var2)
```

calls the function called view and executes the code.

I hope that makes sense. Its not difficult, but a bit tricky to describe.

Comment: This all makes sense. Though, when I defined my FBV_2 inside of my FBV_1, and made FBV_1: 'return FBV_2' -  it still did not work? I get the error: 'function' object has no attribute 'get' - why do I not get this for as_view?

Answer (score 0):

All functions in Python are first-class objects. You don`t have to call it before return, you can do whatever operations you like  with functions without calling them, you can even set attrs for functions:

```
func.level = 5
```

The difference is just when you call function on return, function response would be returned, and when don't the function itself is returned. Basically, is_view method returns the same view function as you would`ve written in your views.py:

```
def view(request):
     ...
     return HttpResponse(...)
```

As you can see it always has request as the first param.